# How to get columns name from sql server view by Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am trying to get columns name from sql view, my view appear like this:

```
name       type         building_id
test       type_test    5
test2      type2_test   6
```

I want to get names(name & type & building_id)
I tried Laravel function getColumnListing() but i get null array

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far and how you access all that data?

Comment: what is expected result pls add it

Comment: Each time you do a fetch you have either an array or an object returned. So for example `$columnNames = array_keys($row);`

Comment: Did you execute a query? Or where do you want to get the columns from? Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select('show columns from table_name'); 
// table_name must be db table name
```

Result

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => {#309 ▼
    +"Field": "id"
    +"Type": "int(10) unsigned"
    +"Null": "NO"
    +"Key": "PRI"
    +"Default": null
    +"Extra": "auto_increment"
  }
  1 => {#311 ▼
    +"Field": "name"
    +"Type": "varchar(100)"
    +"Null": "NO"
    +"Key": ""
    +"Default": null
    +"Extra": ""
  }
  2 => {#312 ▶}
  3 => {#313 ▶}
  4 => {#314 ▶}
]
```